# Why two similar PowerShell copy-Item commands behave differently

Tags: powershell

I have two very similar one line commands but one works and one doesn't with variables.

```
Copy-Item "C:\BadSourceCodes\dropTest\base1\*" -Include "myUsers.Config","myUsers.WSF" -Destination "C:\BadSourceCodes\dropTest\temp1"
```

This just works I have two files and I want them to be copied over to destination folder.

If I create something like this

```
$files = "myUsers.Config,myUsers.WSF"

$tempFiles = [string]::Concat("`"",$files.Replace(",","`",`""),"`"")
$tempFiles
Copy-Item "C:\BadSourceCodes\dropTest\base1\*" -Include $tempFiles -Destination "C:\BadSourceCodes\dropTest\temp1" -Force
```

As soon as I use a variable for Include files it doesn't work.  I have checked with different variations and it doesn't work.

Is the $ variable behaves differently?

I tried following variations like $($tempFiles), '$tempFiles', "$tempFiles".....

**UPDATE:**
I think when I am escaping the quotes and replacing , with "," then it treats quote as a part of the string.  Some how it was the bad approach I took. But what worked is just $files.Split(",") which creates an array of string and Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-Include` argument wants an array of strings, not a list of names in a single string. Put the names in an actual array and it should work:

```
#create an array of strings
$files = "myUsers.Config","myUsers.WSF"

Copy-Item "C:\BadSourceCodes\dropTest\base1\*" -Include $files -Destination "C:\BadSourceCodes\dropTest\temp1" -Force
```

Comment: zdan- in my $tempfiles I concatenate to create an array of strings. Shouldn't that approach work?  Or is it not treating it as an array. Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: What worked was this $tempfiles = $files.Split(",") which created an array of strings but I am still curious why my approach didn't work.  I think the parser thinks the quotes I escaped as part of string may be.

Comment: @Mitul In the approach in your question $tempFiles is a string, it may look like the notation for creating an array, but the parser will never bother parsing it. Just do a $tempFiles.GetType() to see what I mean.